# Why do my headers in TransformRequest become lowercase?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, resources

I have the following codes:

```
save: {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'X-L5S-View-Mode': 'front',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Language': ''
        },
        transformRequest: function (data, getHeaders) {
            console.log(resource.lang);
            var headers = getHeaders();
            headers['Accept-Language'] = resource.lang; 
            console.log(headers);
            return JSON.stringify(data);
        }
    }
```

in my resource factory.
Weirdly, all my headers are converted to lower case.

Here's the log:

```
fr <-- resource.lang
Object {x-l5s-view-mode: "front", content-type: "application/json", accept-language: "", accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*", Accept-Language: "fr"…} <-- headers
```

Why are my headers in lower case?

Plus, when I inspect with Chrome, I found that the `Accept-Language` is blank. So even I have changed the `Accept-Language` with `headers['Accept-Language'] = resource.lang;`, it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Because the latest version of Angular do not support this way to modify the headers anymore.

Angular 1.3.20 works for me.

Just change the version of Angular in bower.json, delete the original Angular, then cd to your directory and run `bower install`.